# Change image on click on some text JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change image on click on section.
Right now I have a list of collapse div, and are working fine, but I want to show a image for each div.
[image]

```
<div class="feature-image">
    <img src="/images/feature-img.png" />
</div>
<div class="feature-image">
    <img src="/images/feature-img.png" />
</div>

<div class="feature-collapse">
    <div class="ser-3-section">
        <div class="schema-faq wp-block-yoast-faq-block">
            <div class="schema-faq-section"><strong class="schema-faq-question"><i class="fas fa-satellite-dish"></i>  Engineering
            </strong>
            <p class="schema-faq-answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="schema-faq wp-block-yoast-faq-block">
            <div class="schema-faq-section"><strong class="schema-faq-question"><i class="fas fa-satellite-dish">  </i>  Marketing</strong>
            <p class="schema-faq-answer">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("strong.schema-faq-question").click(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("active")){
            jQuery("strong.schema-faq-question").removeClass("active");
            jQuery("p.schema-faq-answer").slideUp("slow");
        }else {
            jQuery("strong.schema-faq-question").removeClass("active");
            jQuery(this).addClass("active");
            jQuery("p.schema-faq-answer").slideUp("slow");
            jQuery(this).next().slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to explain better what you want. What image do you want to change, and for which one? Give us as much information as you can, please

Comment: I attach a img. , When I click on title from right ,to change the image. (Each title have a image)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do that with Jquery attr.

Your Image

```
<img id="MyImg" src="some/path" />
```

Your Text

```
<span id="txtChangeImage">Text to change Image</span>
```

Jquery

```
$('#txtChangeImage').click(function(){
     $('#MyImg').attr('src','Your/New/path');
});
```

Comment: This is ok for one img. But in my case a have a list of img. and only one myst be active, the rest will be hidden.

Comment: And where is that list of images? are you having multiple divs with multiple img tags in it? or you have a js array pattern for all the paths?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple divs with img in.

Comment: After looking at your code and your question I am little confused about it, I might get it correctly but I think what you need to do is instead on **removeclass()** or **addclass** use **  jQuery("strong.schema-faq-question").trigger('click'); ** If there is a collapse it would trigger it.

Comment: Yes, i did this now and it works, but for each div I have to add a new id and a new class, that's the sad part. It's not dynamic.